# Energy momentum tensor for a uniform spherical mass in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity

Can someone give the Energy momentum tensor for a uniform spherical mass in general relativity? I am particularly interested in the tensor expression outside the given mass. I am not looking for solutions but an expression for the tensor.

Comment: Outside of the mass, the energy-momentum tensor is zero.  Inside of the mass, the tensor will depend on the equation of state of the mass.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer assume it is uniform and stationary. what is it inside then?

Comment: If it is uniform and static, it will just be a step function. $T_{tt} = \rho \theta(R - r)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jerry said, outside of the mass the energy-momentum tensor is zero. As our mass is uniform and at rest, and assuming no stress or internal pressures, the only nonzero component of $T^{\mu\nu}$ inside of our mass is $T^{00}$, which is the energy density divided by the speed of light squared. In our case, this is given by (as $E=mc^2$):
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
T^{00}&=\frac{u}{c^2}\\
&=\frac{m}{V}\\
&=\frac{3m}{4\pi r^3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $r$ is the radius of our spherical mass. We therefore find that:
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3m}{4\pi r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

Comment: so the tensor is constant everywhere inside the mass give by above?

Comment: Assuming the mass is uniform, then yes.

Comment: If there are no pressures, it's not going to be static for long.

Comment: @EricR.Anschuetz what is $u$ in this case? Energy density?

Comment: @AlexanderCska, yes, $u$ is the energy density.